# 404 working only with wrong extension

Tags: php, apache

My 404 .htaccess works very well when I put a wrong extension at it in place of .php.

Unfortunately the 404 does not work when I put a wrong name with .php.

This is my .htaccess code:

```
<Files ~ "^.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 /404/notfound.html
order deny,allow
```

Comment: What do you see when you specify wrong url, that ends with `.php`?

Comment: let me show u my links
[link]http://www.s376762308.websitehome.co.uk/contactus.php
this does not appear 404 file


it is fine when eextenstion wrong
[link]http://www.s376762308.websitehome.co.uk/contactus.html

Comment: Have you contacted to the support?

Comment: @zerkms you mean with service provider

Comment: yep. Your `.htaccess` looks fine and works well for me. Seems like it is some specific webserver option specified on that server

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because all PHP requests are being sent to the PHP interpreter. I have seen this before on certain setups, normally with optimized PHP, specially configured FastCGI, etc.

What hosting platform are you on? Is it a linux host? You mention Apache. Do you have control over the server? What does php.ini look like?

Are you still having this issue? The links in your post look the same to me.